# Minimal polynomial of $t$ over $k(t^p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am wondering if the following is true:

> The $k$ be a field of characteristic $p \not= 0$. Then $t$ satisfies $x^p-t^p \in
>  k(t^p)[x]$ is irreducible.

My solution(unsure):
We see $f(x)$ (minimal polyonimal of $t$ over $k(t^p)$) divides $x^p-t^p$.  In $k(t)$ , $f(x)=(x-t)^k$, where $k \le p$. But if $0<k<p$, then $f(x) \notin k(t^p)[x]$. Thus, $x^p-t^p$ is irreducible over $k(t^p)[x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what kind of element $t$ is over $k$. For example, if $t\in k$, then $x^p-t^p$ is of course reducible. I guess your $t$ here is transcendental over $k$? In this case, if $x^p-t^p$ is reducible, then it can be decomposed into $(x-t)^m(x-t)^{p-m}$ with $(x-t)^m,(x-t)^{p-m}\in k(t^p)[x]$ for some $1\leqslant m<p$, which implies that $t^m\in k(t^p)$, and this is a contradiction (just consider  $t^m=\frac{f(t^p)}{g(t^p)}$ where $f,g\in k[x]$ and you'll find the degrees of $t^mg(t^p)$ and $f(t^p)$ never coincide).

Comment: Sorry, how did you deduce $t^m \in k(t^p)?$

Comment: @CWL This is because $(x-t)^m\in k(t^p)[x]$ and surely its coefficients lie in $k(t^p)$. Just expand $(x-t)^m$ and you will see $t^m\in k(t^p)$.